# ssh authentication and remote command output's redirection

Tags: bash, ssh, remote, authentication, tcpdump

I need to run a remote capture on a host via ssh and to authenticate twice, but the second prompt is being redirected.

```
ssh -t user@host "sudo tcpdump -s 0 -n -w - -U -i eth0 not port 22" > /tmp/remotecapture.fifo
```

Local host is `OS X 10.8.5` with `bash 4.3.42(1)`.
Remote host is `Ubuntu Server 14.04.3` with `tcpdump 4.5.1`.

How can I work around this without resorting to using root?

Comment: One option would be to mangle `sudoers` to allow the `tcpdump` (possibly via a wrapper program) via `NOPASSWD`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sudo read password from `stdin`

```
ssh -t user@host "echo yourpassword | sudo -S tcpdump ....."
```

Comment: Then make `tcpdump` run passwordless as suggested by @thrig

Comment: That works, but not with a `named pipe`.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: If `ssh` redirects to a `named pipe` it doesn't prompt to authenticate the remote host and still passes `sudo`'s prompt to the `named pipe`. Try locally `$ echo PASSWORD | sudo -S tcpdump` to get `[sudo] password for default: tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
?V?W **PV?˰`.